# How to open popup on page load only if link is available

Tags: javascript, html

I found code for open popup on page load, but i cant figure out how to open a popup link on pageload only if Link is added. If link is empty, it does nothing.

I am using my code from [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_88.html).

**Javascript**

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
    function popup(mylink, windowname) 
    {
        if (!window.focus)
            return true;
        var href;
        if (typeof (mylink) == 'string')
            href = mylink;
        else
            href = mylink.href;
        window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
        return false;
    }
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

**HTML**

```
<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```

Comment: Any code or example ?

Comment: Hello i am currently using code from http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_88.html , Ive used this method for dynamic links, and its working but in Empety links it keep opening same page, so its in loop. So thats why is there any way if there is no link it ignore code.

Answer (score 0):

IF i understood your question, you need to use a condition before you open the new document.

```
if (href !== '' && href !== null) {
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
}
```

Comment: Hello this is my code, i am sorry i am not a programmer, can you suggest me correction<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

Comment: I've opened the link what you show me. Add the condition around the `window.open` line.

Comment: @NirajChoksi you might wanna update the answer with that code.